# How to delete a VPN connection in Windows 8?

Tags: networking, windows-8, vpn

How do i delete a VPN connection in Windows 8?

---

In Windows 8 i can have VPN connections:

[image]

How do i delete them?

Things i've tried:

- right-clicking the connection name
- hold-clicking the connection name
- sliding to the left on the connection name
- slide to the right
- two hops this time
- take it back now y'all
- putting my hands in the air like i just don't care

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Windows, standard VPN connections are considered "Dial-up adapters".

Go into "Change Adapter Settings" in the left-hand pane of the Network and Sharing Center, and delete it there.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

1. Move to the right of your screen
2. Click "Settings"
3. Choose "Change PC Settings"
4. Choose "Network" and then "Connections"
5. Click on the connection you want to delete and then on "remove"

and another way:

1. Go to "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk"
2. Delete the "rasphone.pbk" file